# Redirect to shorter url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect *mywebsite.com/?event=something* to *mywebsite.com/something*

I'm hoping to skip the Wordpress Event pages my pluging makes and instead redirect to posts I make with the same name.

I have:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Where should I place an extra line and with what?

This is very helpfull: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
but haven't found a working solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+\?event=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: @user4641632 at the very top, above all the wordpress stuff

Comment: @user4641632 it works [perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WPmnc.png)